# tkinter not connecting to a while loop/ if statement

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, tkinter

I've created a program that basically validates a car registration number, preforms a speed calculation then writes the users details to a notepad if they have an invalid registration number or have broken the speed limit, it works fine. Now im trying to make it more interactive my using tkinter but for some reason it's not connecting to the while loop.

tkinter program:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import randint
import re

def show_entry_fields():
   print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nRegistration number:%s" %        (Fname.get(), Lname.get(), reg.get()))

momma = Tk()
Label(momma, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(momma, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
Label(momma, text="please enter your registration number:").grid(row=2)

Fname = Entry(momma)
Lname = Entry(momma)
reg = Entry(momma)

Fname.grid(row=0, column=1)#colim = Insert the widget at this column.
Lname.grid(row=1, column=1)
reg.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(momma, text='Quit', command=momma.quit).grid(row=3, column=0,               sticky=W, pady=4) 
Button(momma, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()



while reg== re.match('^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$', reg):
   w= Message(momma, text="that is a valid registration number")
   w.pack()
   break
```

would just really like some help with connecting the start of the program to the while loop. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is only entered after the mainloop has finished, which is after the Tk window has closed. What you want is to do the regex when you press the button, which is in the `show_entry_fields` function. your while expression doesn't make much sense either, it's never going to be True:

```
from tkinter import *
import re

def show_entry_fields():
    print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nRegistration number:%s" % (Fname.get(), Lname.get(), reg.get()))
    if re.match('^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}$', reg.get()):
        w.configure(text='That is a valid registration number')
        # Do what you want to do after a valid registration number is entered, close the window, call a new function, whatever you want
    else:
        w.configure(text='Invalid registration number')

momma = Tk()
Label(momma, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(momma, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)
Label(momma, text="please enter your registration number:").grid(row=2)
w= Label(momma, text="")

Fname = Entry(momma)
Lname = Entry(momma)
reg = Entry(momma)

Fname.grid(row=0, column=1)#colim = Insert the widget at this column.
Lname.grid(row=1, column=1)
reg.grid(row=2, column=1)
w.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)

Button(momma, text='Quit', command=momma.quit).grid(row=3, column=0,sticky=W, pady=4) 
Button(momma, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

momma.mainloop()
```